# consistency among different training pairs of skip-gram model

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

Regarding skip-gram model, for training purpose, the input is a word (one-hot representation) and outputs are its context words (multiple one-hot representations). For example, (A,B), (A,C), (A, D)
My question is: when we are running the training process, we are running the model pair by pair or we just feed in [A, B|C|D] altogether?

Another question is regarding the word vector matrix "M" (matrix between input and hidden layer). Since input is one-hot, so the result of input (size |V|) x M is a vector of size |V| which is a row of the word vector matrix. My question is: when we are running the back propagation, it seems only that row of word vector matrix updated.

Is this true?

If that is the case and suppose we are training the model pair by pair (A,B), (A,C), (A, D), how to keep the consistency among the different back propagation of different pairs? For example, once pair (A,B) is done, the row in word vector matrix got updated. Through the update, the error will become less for (A,B). Then we run pair (A,C), the same row is picked and got updated through back propagation. Now this time, the error will become less for (A,C). But the correction for (A,B) will be erased, which means the back propagation of (A,B) is discarded. Is my understanding correct here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as presenting the pairs, individually as training examples: (A, B), (A, C), (A, D). That's how the algorithm is defined. (However, some implementations might in practice be able to do them as a batch.)

Note that 'outputs' are only "one-hot" when using negative-sampling. (In hierarchical-softmax, predicting one word requires a variable huffman-coded set of output nodes to have specific 0/1 values.)

Yes, in skip-gram, each training example (such as "A predicts B") only results in a single word's vector ("row of word vector matrix") being updated, since only one word is involved.

Note that while the paper describes using a focus word to predict its nearby words, the released Google word2vec.c code (and other implementations modeled on it) as a matter of implementation uses context words to predict the focus word. Essentially it'd just a different way of structuring the loops (and thus ordering the training pair examples), which I believe they did for slightly better CPU cache efficiency.

In your scenario, the subsequent backprop for the (A, C) example does not necessarily "erase" the prior (A, B) backprop – depending on the out-representations of B & C, it might reinforce it (in some ways/directions/dimensions), or weaken it (in other ways/directions/dimensions). It is essentially that repeated tug-of-war, between all the diverse examples, that eventually creates an arrangement of weights which somehow reflect some useful similarities of A, B, and C.

The best way to rigorously understand what is happening is to review the source code of implementations, such as the [original Google word2vec.c](https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec/blob/master/word2vec.c) or the [Python implementation in gensim](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py).